# Running Oracle IMP as SYSDBA

Tags: oracle, imp, sysdba

I need to import an ORACLE 9 DMP file into a newly installed Oracle 11g.  I'm using the imp utility and using SYSMAN as the login.  I get to the point to restore and am told 'only a DBA can import a file exported by another DBA'.  When I try and use SYSDBA blank password does not work.  When I use SQLPLUS / as SYSDBA and then try and assign a new password I'm told SYSDBA does not exist.  If I try and log in as SYS I'm told to login as SYSDBA.

Comment: What do you mean by 'use SYSDBA blank password'? `SYSDBA’ is a system privilege, not a user or role. It sounds like you need to run it as `SYS` with the `SYSDBA` privilege. What does `imp '/ as sysdba' ... ` do? Also, do you know what's in the file - make sure you're not importing anything that will conflict with your current DB, particulary if it was a full export and you're doing a full import.

Comment: What OS platform are you on?  Did you try SYSTEM?  Are you running on the DB server?

Answer (score 8):

Try following syntax to use `imp` as `sysdba`:

```
imp \'sys/sys as sysdba\' file=/oracle/implog.dmp log=imp.log full=y
```

Comment: using the above to import a DMP file exported while connected as sysdba (escaping quotes was not needed in windows 7 at least) created all objects with SYS as owner :( a particularly bad situation. i think "full=y" does that. i ended up creating the desired user, with all necessary privileges granted, logging in as that user and and running imp with fromuser / touser specified, but in that case somehow other objects like packages were not imported - had to import them from generated (exported) schema creation script. a mess.

Answer (score 4):

I used the syntax below:

```
imp userid='sys/password@host as sysdba' log=C:\dmp.log file=C:\dmp.dmp fromuser=userfrom touser=userto buffer=30720
```

Comment: apparently, this syntax doesn't work on windows